# In JReport, how can I use the value of main report's field in UDS into formula of sub report?

Tags: report

In Jreport, I have a main report and a sub report. The data module is 1 : n for main report and sub report. Now I need to use main report's field in UDS as the column header in sub report, and suppress the header if the value in the field is null. To implement this, I create a parameter in catalog to receive the field value from main report. With this, the columns header in sub report are shown correctly, but if I create a formula to toggle suppress/show and use it in the column header, the data in sub report disappeared.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sort out this issue by add line "pagenumber;" in the top of the formula.